# Facing Following Issues When Submitting App to App Store

Tags: iphone

When I submit the application to app store I get the following errors:

1) Apple's web service operation was not successful

2) Unable to authenticate the package 444.itmsp

3) The filename -23Pop.isa in the package contains an invalid character(s). The valid characters are A-Z (and so on).

Comment: itunesconnect is not working today... probably due to all the Lion stuff and the Mac App Store testing...

Answer (score 1):

Found the problem. The problem was related to the app name which should not start with a number. I changed the app name to something else and it went through fine!